# Unable to find directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am trying to import training dataset GoogleNews-vector-negative300.bin and unable to do so. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

When I run the code.

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model_path = './data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)
```

I get this error. Can you please tell me how can I remove this?

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-04e6454088bc> in <module>
      1 from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
      2 model_path = './data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
----> 3 w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\channel\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
   1434         return _load_word2vec_format(
   1435             cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding, unicode_errors=unicode_errors,
-> 1436             limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
   1437 
   1438     def get_keras_embedding(self, train_embeddings=False):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\channel\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
    169 
    170     logger.info("loading projection weights from %s", fname)
--> 171     with utils.smart_open(fname) as fin:
    172         header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
    173         vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\channel\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py in smart_open(uri, mode, **kw)
    398             transport_params[key] = value
    399 
--> 400     return open(uri, mode, ignore_ext=ignore_extension, transport_params=transport_params, **scrubbed_kwargs)
    401 
    402 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\channel\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py in open(uri, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline, closefd, opener, ignore_ext, transport_params)
    298         buffering=buffering,
    299         encoding=encoding,
--> 300         errors=errors,
    301     )
    302     if fobj is not None:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\channel\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py in _shortcut_open(uri, mode, ignore_ext, buffering, encoding, errors)
    457     #
    458     if six.PY3:
--> 459         return _builtin_open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode, buffering=buffering, **open_kwargs)
    460     elif not open_kwargs:
    461         return _builtin_open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode, buffering=buffering)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
```

Comment: The error sometimes comes when the file is open in your system, try closing and running the code again

Comment: Still getting the same error. Do I need to download this first GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin?

Comment: Inorder to make this code work, you have to download `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` and keep it in a folder named `data`

Comment: @BrandLee: Absolutely Yes!!

Comment: This is what I get when I put it in E drive.
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\GoogleNews_vectors_negative300.bin'

Comment: I have change the 
model path='E:\\GoogleNews_vectors_negative300.bin'